# Why is the fermionic sector of Standard Model the way it is?

Tags: experimental-physics, standard-model, history, weak-interaction, electroweak

"Because it works!" will be considered too broad an answer. I want to precisely know which experiments forced to consider the model construction the way it is. For example, I can see Wu's experiment dictates that parity is maximally violated so to incorporate that the left projection of the electron is put in a $SU(2)$ doublet but the right projection is a $SU(2)$ singlet.

Also, there is a subtlety here also---the quantity measured in Wu's experiment is helicity not chirality which isn't the same for massive leptons like electrons. But when we construct the electroweak theory we put the left chiral part in a $SU(2)$ doublet. After discussion in the hbar, I thought that this might be because helicity $\sim$ chirality in the ultrarelativistic limit in which HEP operates mostly or maybe because when we are writing the Lagrangian no symmetry breaking has occurred so everything's massless (might be false reasoning) or because it simply works for the neutrino where helicity=chirality so it's natural that it works also for the electron.

I have a few specific questions in mind to begin with apart from the above---

a) What made us put the electron with the electron neutrino amongst other things like other neutrinos, other massive leptons?

b) Wu's experiment was done with electrons? What were the corresponding experiments with the other leptons/quarks?

c) Would a model having say the left projection of up quark and the down quark in different $SU(2)$ doublets work?

d) If non-trivial transformation under $SU(2)$ is the thing required of the left projections, why not combine the three massive leptons in a triplet and the three neutrinos in another or all of them in a 6 dimensional representation?  (One guess is all three were not known at the same time, and by the time they were known making doublets already gave fruitful results so nobody cared about this/ cared and didn't work out. Or might be because they don't "mix"---again which
experiments say these? Or is it just Occam's razor doin' it's magic?)

e) Why don't the quarks and leptons be put together in any case? (Problems with CKM mixing?)

If these questions are too broad, I would like to see some books/papers addressing this preferably not from the theoretical side because in theory we already write down the model and explore the rich consequences. I want to know how people wrote down the model. E.g. The Higgs sector is surprisingly well explained in books. For example, why it's a doublet, why the potential *can be* Sombero hat type, why scalar field etc. etc.---probably because Higgs was detected *after* the model was made.
If there are some theoretical inconsistencies in the other "options" then please point them out, also.

It will be surprising to me if the answer is really that it happened by accident or people actually made "all" possible theories and the standard model became the unique theory which matches all the experiments of that time.

Lastly, I don't know if this question is suited more for this site or History of Science and Mathematics.

Comment: "Why don't the quarks and leptons be put together in any case?" They are put into combined representations in grand unified theories. But this leads e.g. to proton decay, which has not been observed.

Comment: I won't do justice to the specifics if I try writing an answer, but it's a combination of beta decays, solar neutrino flux composition, paths and lifetimes of mu and tau decays, non-observation of proton decay, empirical scalar/pseudoscalar distinctions, evidence weak interactions are $V-A$ etc. As for "how people wrote down the model", the Dirac equation inspires specific ways to add matter to classical electromagnetism, and then you make non-Abelian generalizations with empirically motivated gauge groups.

Comment: It is a long and almost "inevitable" story, best summarized in A Pais' "Inward bound", and, formally, in TD Lee's "Particle Physics". It underlies on a "huge" number of concepts and experiments and theoretical constructions you may have to have fully mastered the SM as is, in the first place. Only *then* are you prepared how the sudoku pieces fit together, and there is no other way....

Comment: Did the SM start with the Perodic Table, or JJ Thomson discovering the electron? There's a lot of golf between either and the LHC.